# GNUplot plot function doesn't save file

Tags: gnuplot, homebrew

Ive installed GNUplot on OSX using

```
brew install gnuplot
```

in terminal. I can open gnuplot using

```
gnuplot
```

in terminal. I then use

```
set terminal png
```

But then if I try to plot anything I just get random characters printed to the screen.

e.g

```
plot sin(x)/x
```

returns

```
     Q%@??L?r??T?   89??? ?v?*?`"?Ө~???;???o.?/???jk??W}???f??C8???rR??2j??        GE?e.?fJ??zv!S?f]|???=?^<}?Bq?m??
    ^<??C&G{nR?Ũ?"~?(YA@?????ϱ??????yd?В->桮???o??~??*-R??m???Q??????Я??=?
    ң?9????(Z<?C]???߫???\?wH??Ѧ??(Z?C_???ww???w??ǣ??txE??y???F??q%?n??Q???ǁ|????(Z???X@???V??q3????Pӣ??y?y?e?p???EHK?y????xj?l7?{ݟ?g?1BG?Q?8???g/oD??k#g??h?1}=?n????:????<?????
           ??Ń'?IEND?B`?gnuplot>
```

The same thing happens if I set the terminal to jpeg.

Answer (score 2):

gnuplot just prints the contents of a png file that you want to create. You should specify the file name:

```
set output "myfile.png"
```

Comment: Great! Thanks very much.